# Error while compiling a program to publish a string in a custom topic

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to publish a string under the topic, name. But I'm getting compile error and I can't figure out where exactly the problem lies also. Could someone help me out.
This is my pubname.cpp file.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc,argv,"pubname"); //node name is pubname
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("name",1000); //topic is name
    


ros::Rate rate(2);

while(ros::ok())
{
std_msgs::String msg("Patrick");
pub.publish(msg);
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending Name ");
rate.sleep();
}
}
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(assignment2)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs)
catkin_package()
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(pubname pubname.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pubname ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target pubname
[100%] Building CXX object assignment2/CMakeFiles/pubname.dir/pubname.cpp.o
/home/Patrick/ROSthings/Auro2/src/assignment2/pubname.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/Patrick/ROSthings/Auro2/src/assignment2/pubname.cpp:16:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >::String_(const char [16])’
 std_msgs::String msg("Patrick");
                                       ^
/home/Patrick/ROSthings/Auro2/src/assignment2/pubname.cpp:16:39: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/Patrick/ROSthings/Auro2/src/assignment2/pubname.cpp:2:0:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/std_msgs/String.h:62:3: note: std_msgs::String_<ContainerAllocator>::String_(const ContainerAllocator&) [with ContainerAllocator = std::allocator<void>]
   String_(const ContainerAllocator& _alloc)
   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/std_msgs/String.h:62:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [16]’ to ‘const std::allocator<void>&’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/std_msgs/String.h:59:3: note: std_msgs::String_<ContainerAllocator>::String_() [with ContainerAllocator = std::allocator<void>]
   String_()
   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/std_msgs/String.h:59:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/opt/ros/indigo/include/std_msgs/String.h:55:8: note: std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >::String_(const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >&)
 struct String_
        ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/std_msgs/String.h:55:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [16]’ to ‘const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >&’
make[2]: *** [assignment2/CMakeFiles/pubname.dir/pubname.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [assignment2/CMakeFiles/pubname.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192086/error-while-compiling-a-program-to-publish-a-string-in-a-custom-topic./) by [lffox](https://answers.ros.org/users/20121/lffox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-06**:
please post  error message

**Comment by [lffox](https://answers.ros.org/users/20121/lffox/) on 2014-09-06**:
hello, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add dependencies in `CmakeLists.txt`

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  )
```

and in `package.xml`

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  
  
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
```

**Edit:**
replace string message initialization of

```
std_msgs::String msg("Patrick");
```

with

```
std_msgs::String msg;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Patrick " << count;
msg.data = ss.str();
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lffox](https://answers.ros.org/users/20121/lffox/) on 2014-09-06**:
I have added those dependencies in CMakeLists.txt. Haven't edited the xml file though, can it result in compile errors?

**Comment by [lffox](https://answers.ros.org/users/20121/lffox/) on 2014-09-06**:
I tried editing the xml file also, but still same error.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-06**:
check the updated answer.

**Comment by [lffox](https://answers.ros.org/users/20121/lffox/) on 2014-09-06**:
Hello, it worked. Can you tell me why we have it to do this way? I saw the same in the ROSwiki also. Thank you

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-06**:
std_msgs::String is not same as c++ std::string, its ROS message which has  string type variable data

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2017-04-12**:
It can also be done this way:

```
std_msgs::String msg;
msg.data = "hello";
```